# Adding MSBuild Community Tasks as an Agent Requirement

Tags: teamcity

My build script depends on the MSBuild Community Task targets. I'd like to make this an agent requirement. How can this be done in TeamCity 8.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add an Agent Requirement (Step 8 of your build Configuration)

[image]

Now immediately after doing this your build agent will be incompatible - that is because there is no such environment variable as `MSBuildCommunityTasksPath` - I've made this up because Community Tasks does not install any.

The next thing you need to do is log into the build agent PCs that *do* have Community Tasks installed and add this environment variable:

[image]

the path should be either

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks` 
or

`C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks`

*nb techincally it doesnt matter what you enter as this variable is just a flag indicating community tasks is installed*

after you do this **you need to restart your build agent**

Now this paramter will be available in TeamCity and your build agent should be compatible. You can go to the Agents tab to check this. `Agents -> <your agent> -> Agent parameters -> Environment Variables`

[image]

Comment: Are there any alternatives to using environment variables? E.g. like a required file path `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks` parameter? I just hate having external configuration dependencies.

Comment: Yea I had a good look for that; I couldnt find any, this is the best I could come up with

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to reference the nuget package rather and known version than what might be installed on a target machine?

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden please elaborate. i install build tasks as a standalone